# How to do the opposite to Width="150*" in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like for the Width attribute to dynamically expand until it reaches 150, and after this, user should be able to expand it further via drag (MaxWidth won't allow this).

```
Width="150*"
```

has similar functionality, but in the opposite direction(minimum width and expand as needed). I want to have "expand as needed" and maximum expansion width.

Is there any way this can be done using XAML?

Comment: Have you tried `MaxWidth="150"` in Combination with `Width="Auto"` ? This should ensure that the space is allocated as needed but only up to 150px. Using Star-Syntax will not work, it merely describes relative width (in comparison to siblings).

Comment: yes, any use of MaxWidth causes the user not to be able to resize the control to the size that is larger than the MaxWidth. I want for the MaxWidth to apply to Auto-sizing only, not to what the user can do

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"the opposite to Width="150*"`?

Answer (score 0):

Put a line on the edge that you want the user to be able to drag.  Set the Cursor property to "SizeWE"  on that line so that the user knows he can drag it.  From that line, handle the mouse down, mouse move, and mouse up events.  In the MouseDown call CaptureMouse() from the line control and save the mouse position.  On mouse move, get the new mouse position, calculate the change from the mouse down position, and increase the width of the control that you were constraining to 150 by the amount of the mouse move in the right direction and then reset the original mouse position to the current mouse position.  On MouseUp, call ReleaseMouse() from the line control.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the width depending on the size of the item. Bind the width to a `GridLength` and then you can let the user control it, or control it yourself up to 150

```
private GridLength _marquee1Width = new GridLength(150, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```

You can set this to `GridUnitType.Pixel`, `GridUnitType.Auto`, or `GridUnitType.Star`